# caffe installation error linker error lib/libcaffe.dylib Error and src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all Error

Tags: opencv, osx-mavericks, caffe

I have been trying to install caffe on my mac OSX 10.9.5.
I have been following the official caffe installation from  http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation.

When I am following the cmake installation's "make all" in build folder, I keep on getting the following linking error. I have been trying many possible suggestions that I have found on the web but to no avail.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [lib/libcaffe.dylib] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The full error log is at https://github.com/jackywang529/myOpenCV/blob/master/OpenCV/OpenCVTutorial2/errorLog

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from CUDA6.5 to CUDA7.0, the "make all" step completed successfully. I also made sure that I removed the edits that I had made to the formulas, which were necessary when I was using CUDA6.5. Such edits is described in (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html under section libstdc++ installation).

Good luck with all caffe users!